# Count amount of records per account group, where joined date = each month

Tags: mysql, count

I have a table (accounts) that holds the accountgroup and joineddate of accounts, amongst other fields. Using MySQL version 5.5.35-cll.

Essentially what I'm trying to do is count the amount of 'registrations' that happen each month, per accountgroup. (Not just the total amount per month - need to know how many registrations are occurring in each accountgroup, each month).

So the result would look something like this:

[intended results http://imageshack.com/a/img842/9105/drh9.gif](http://imageshack.com/a/img842/9105/drh9.gif)

I've tried a few different approaches, but have only been successful getting what I need for one specified month, as opposed to all months of the year.  When I tried to use SUM it looked like it was working, but it didn't work as expected - would seem like it thought there was a maximum of 1 registrations per month per group, when in reality there are at least 4 or 5 for some groups.

This is my most recent (failing) attempt with SUM:

```
SELECT accountgroup, 
SUM( IF( MONTH =1, numRecords, 0 ) AND YEAR=2014) AS  'January', 
SUM( IF( MONTH =2, numRecords, 0 ) AND YEAR=2014) AS  'February', 
SUM( IF( MONTH =3, numRecords, 0 ) AND YEAR=2014) AS  'March', 
SUM( IF( MONTH =4, numRecords, 0 ) AND YEAR=2014) AS  'April', 
SUM( IF( MONTH =5, numRecords, 0 ) AND YEAR=2014) AS  'May', 
SUM( IF( MONTH =6, numRecords, 0 ) AND YEAR=2014) AS  'June', 
SUM( IF( MONTH =7, numRecords, 0 ) AND YEAR=2014) AS  'July', 
SUM( IF( MONTH =8, numRecords, 0 ) AND YEAR=2014) AS  'August', 
SUM( IF( MONTH =9, numRecords, 0 ) AND YEAR=2014) AS  'September', 
SUM( IF( MONTH =10, numRecords, 0 ) AND YEAR=2014) AS  'October', 
SUM( IF( MONTH =11, numRecords, 0 ) AND YEAR=2014) AS  'November', 
SUM( IF( MONTH =12, numRecords, 0 ) AND YEAR=2014) AS  'December', 
SUM( numRecords ) AS total
FROM (
SELECT accountgroup, MONTH( joineddate ) AS MONTH, YEAR( joineddate ) AS YEAR, COUNT( * ) AS numRecords
FROM accounts 
WHERE accountgroup <>''
GROUP BY accountgroup, MONTH, YEAR) AS SubTable1
GROUP BY accountgroup");
```

**Anyone able to show me how to do this? I'm pretty stumped :(

Thanks in advance for any help.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close.  You need to put the `year` condition inside the `if`.  For example:

```
SUM(IF(MONTH = 1 AND YEAR = 2014, numRecords, 0)) AS January, 
SUM(IF(MONTH = 2 AND YEAR = 2014, numRecords, 0)) AS February, 
. . .
```

You don't need the final parentheses.  So, the query should look like:

```
SELECT accountgroup, 
       SUM(IF(MONTH = 1 AND YEAR = 2014, numRecords, 0)) AS January, 
       SUM(IF(MONTH = 2 AND YEAR = 2014, numRecords, 0)) AS February, 
       . . . 
       SUM( numRecords ) AS total
FROM (SELECT accountgroup, MONTH( joineddate ) AS MONTH, YEAR( joineddate ) AS YEAR, COUNT( * ) AS numRecords
      FROM accounts 
      WHERE accountgroup <>''
      GROUP BY accountgroup, MONTH, YEAR
     ) AS SubTable1
GROUP BY accountgroup";
```

Also, do not use single quotes on things that should be column or table names.  You do not need to escape these names in this case.  Use double quotes or backticks.  Only use single quotes for string and date constants.